# Why are the general solutions for $x$ of $ \sin(\pi-x)=0$ and $ \sin(x-\pi)=0$ different?

Tags: trigonometry

> If, $$ \sin(π-x)=0$$
> Then, $ \sin(x-π)=0 $ [multiplying by $(-1)$ on both sides]

But since general solution of $ \sin x=0 $ is $ x=n\pi $ Above equations yield

$$ x=\pi - n\pi $$

And $$ x = \pi +n\pi $$

Is it okay to use either of equations $ \sin(π-x)=0 $ and $ \sin(x-π)=0 $ when finding general solution? Or am I free to multiply the equation with $(-1)$?

Comment: I don't see a reason to downvote. The question might be elementary, but it is clearly stated and shows effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that in both your solutions $n \in \mathbb Z$, and one of them becomes another using the substitution $n \mapsto -n$. So, these might be different *expressions*, but the *solution sets* they describe are exactly the same.